# Можно ли настроить проброс X11 в уже активной сессии SSH?

Tags: ssh, unix, x11

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.  Есть уже открытое
*SSH*-соединение.  Оно было открыто без опций
`-X`/`-Y`.  Можно ли активировать проброс *X*
несмотря на это?

Comment: Через парамико вроде можно добавлять каналы на лету, а в openssh не видел такого интерфейса.